# Getting kafka topic related issue in spring boot service

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

We have a spring boot service that always gets this error when starting up:

```
org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: Failed to create topics; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Call(callName=createTopics, deadlineMs=1646313594248, tries=1, nextAllowedTryMs=-9223372036854775709) timed out at 9223372036854775807 after 1 attempt(s)
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaAdmin.addTopics(KafkaAdmin.java:281) ~[spring-kafka-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaAdmin.addTopicsIfNeeded(KafkaAdmin.java:221) ~[spring-kafka-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaAdmin.initialize(KafkaAdmin.java:189) [spring-kafka-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaAdmin.afterSingletonsInstantiated(KafkaAdmin.java:157) [spring-kafka-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:963) [spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) [spring-context-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) [spring-context-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144) [spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:782) [spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:774) [spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:439) [spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:339) [spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1340) [spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1329) [spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at com.medfusion.apt.event.collector.Starter.main(Starter.java:24) [classes/:?]
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Call(callName=createTopics, deadlineMs=1646313594248, tries=1, nextAllowedTryMs=-9223372036854775709) timed out at 9223372036854775807 after 1 attempt(s)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: The AdminClient thread has exited.
```

However, the application continues to startup correctly.
This is not happening with all services, this is happening with 3 service.

Any suggestions, how can I make it go away.

Comment: According to the error, the topics you're trying to use cannot be created. It may not prevent startup, but it might cause runtime issues later

Comment: It might mean that your application does not have access to the broker's admin functions - you'd have to check with the team responsible for that.

Comment: @TomazFernandes Yeah that was the issue. added admin broker related properties. and it worked. thanks.

Comment: I'm glad it worked. I've added an answer with that comment so, if you think it's ok, you can select that as correct and make it easier for other people to find it. Also feel free to add any comments on what exactly you had to do. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might mean that your application does not have access to the broker's admin functions - you'd have to check with the team responsible for that.

Comment: @Akshay what properties exactly ?